# Where do I find more documentation on how to stub an application in MobileFirst TestWorkbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a hybrid application that uses the native camera.
The recording promptly misses the camera part.

In the recording, the part before the camera shows in an Application details box called *Launch application: whatever*, while the post camera portion, well it shows under a new Application Details thingie called *In application: whatever*.

How do I stub it?
It seems that whatever I add, as an Application Stub, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problems with Mobile Test Workbench, and the documentation is not enough and you are unable to resolve your problem, you can open an IBM PMR (support ticket) and have it directed for the MTW team.